# WebPart made of user controls

Tags: visual-studio, web-part, user-controls

I have a number of custom web parts which have similar functions and properties shared through each of them.  Each have a subset of a larger set of functions, rather than redevelop the same controls over and over, is there a way I can build the user controls and then just drag and drop it on to my Visual Web Part as I would any other web project?

What I have is structured as follows:

1. A number of web parts
2. A Mapped folder for ControlTemplates with a sub folder for MyCustomControls
3. User controls in the MyCustomControls folder.

When I drag and drop the user control into my Visual Web Part User control, all it does is add the path to the web part user control as a string. i.e. `D:\Source\MyProject\ControlTemplates\MyCustomControls\CustomControl.ascx`

There is nothing difficult in the web part yet, its purely HTML markup (at the moment):

```
<a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="floatright">
Content Title
</a>
<!-- ui-dialog -->
<div id="dialog" title="Content Title">
    <p>Brief content</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the user control was referenced as @Sébastien Levert
said but was placed in the mapped folder `ControlTemplates`, however `ControlTemplates` is actually referred to as `_ControlTemplates` in the web.config when running SP2010, the solution was to change the mapped folder in VS to `_ControlTemplates` mimicking the safe entry in the web.config

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a reference to it in your container webpart.  Like this :

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="MyTagPrefix" Namespace="My.WebControls.Namespace" Assembly="My.Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=MYPUBLICKEYTOKEN" %>
```

Then, you can use this new refered namespace this way in your container webpart :

```
<MyTagPrefix:MyControl id="Control1" runat="server"/>
```

Good luck !

Comment: I found the issue, the user control was referenced as you said but was placed in the mapped folder `ControlTemplates`, however ControlTemplates is actually referred to as `_ControlTemplates` when running SP2010, the solution was to change the mapped folder in VS to `_ControlTemplates` mimicking the safe entry in the web.config

Comment: Absolutely right.  Glad you found your precise solution :)